# Rails 4.2 - Link to create action with Javascript results in 302

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app in which I have a dynamic form. One of the fields have a "submit" button of it's own. It looks something like this:

```
----------------
| Normal field |
----------------

-------------------------
| "Value"      | Submit |
-------------------------
List of "Values"

----------------
| Normal field |
----------------
----------------
| Submit       |
----------------
```

Users should be able to add "Values" either by hitting the fields submit button or the general submit button for the form, displaying a flash message if it's successful or if there was some error.

The `"Value"` object in the example above is in my app called `valid_domain`.

I've got it to create the objects, but I keep getting `Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)` from the server when clicking the field's submit button.

The relevant parts of my form looks like this:

```
/ My domain field 
= f.text_field :domain, placeholder: "yourdomain.com", :class => "form-control"
  %span.input-group-btn
    %button.btn.btn-default
      = link_to "Add domain", "#", class: "add-domain"

/ List of domains
- if @team.valid_domains.any?
  %ul.list-unstyled#domain-list
    - @team.valid_domains.each do |domain_model|
      = render "valid_domains/domain", domain_model: domain_model
```

When users clicks my `Add domain` button I handle it with javascript (coffee script) that looks like this:

```
jQuery ->

  $(".add-domain").on "click", (event) ->
    event.preventDefault() # don't trigger default

    domain_name = $("#team_valid_domain_domain").val()
    team_id = $("#team_id_field").val()

    $.post "/teams/#{team_id}/valid_domains", domain: domain_name, team_id: team_id, (data) ->
```

My `valid_domains` create action looks like this:

```
def create
  team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])
  if params[:valid_domain].present?
    @valid_domain = team.valid_domains.create(params[:valid_domain].permit(:team_id, :domain))
  else
    @valid_domain = team.valid_domains.create(params.permit(:domain, :team_id))
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @valid_domain.save
      format.html { redirect_to edit_team_path(team), notice: 'Domain added' }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@valid_domain) }
      format.js   { render action: 'create', status: :created, location: @valid_domain }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to edit_team_path(team), alert: "Couldn't create domain" }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@valid_domain) }
    end
  end
end
```

As noted, clicking the `Add domain` button creates the object but the server returns `302`.

Any ideas on how I can solve that?

In the best I would also like to update my `#domain-list` `ul` dynamically with Ajax/Javascript when the create action is successful, but I can't get it to works. Think it's because my `302` error code. I have created a `create.js.erb` file that looks like this:

```
$('#domain-list').append("<%= j render partial: 'valid_domains/domain', locals:   {domain_model: @valid_domain } %>").children(':first').hide().slideDown('fast');
$("#flash").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/flash' %>").slideDown('fast');

$(".close").click(function(){
  $(".alert").slideUp('fast');
});
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to work would be appreciated. General code improvement comments would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your AJAX request is being processed as HTML instead of JS (take a look at your log file to confirm, check for lines like `Processing by YourController#create as HTML`).

The solution would be to update you CoffeScript as follows:

```
add_domain_handler = (data) ->
  # whatever you want to do
  return

jQuery ->

  $(".add-domain").on "click", (event) ->
    event.preventDefault() # don't trigger default

    domain_name = $("#team_valid_domain_domain").val()
    team_id = $("#team_id_field").val()

    $.post "/teams/#{team_id}/valid_domains", domain: domain_name, team_id: team_id, add_domain_handler, 'script'
```

This will tell jQuery to ask for JS instead of HTML in the `Content-Type` header, and will make Rails respond with the correct format.